# How does Space-Time Cloak work?

Tags: general-relativity

Well, scientists have achieved [Spacetime cloaking to make events fully disappear](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/07/110711-invisibility-cloak-events-space-time-bank-robbery-science/). Currently, it works only for a trillionth of a second, but here's real-world scenario from linked page:

> In theory, the cloak would slow down light coming into the robbery scene while the safecracker is at work. When the robbery is complete, the process would be reversed, with the slowed light now racing to catch back up.
>
> If the "before" and "after" visions are seamlessly stitched together, there should be no visible trace that anything untoward has happened. One second there's a closed safe, and the next second the safe has been emptied.

The project is exploiting General Theory of Relativity meaning it's compatible with the theory. How are they doing that?

Light can be slowed down and speed up in materials, but to match slow down, speeding up needs to cross $c$ which is impossible. Talking about Spacetime curvatures, first problem is creating a Spacetime curvature enough influential to bend light, all without using high amount of mass-energy. Second, gravitational lensing (Spacetime curved geodesic) just changes direction of light from flat Spacetime perspective. How would it account for speeding up to accommodate slowing down? Time Dilation and Length contractions are irrelevant (for cloak our reference frames need to be affected) and aren't applicable to light.

Show some light, please.

Comment: More on cloaking in time: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+cloak+time